# How can I use recursion with reflection in order to investigate class instance with cyclic dependency?

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, recursion

Consider you have the following class:

```
Class P  
{  
     string m_Name;  
     P m_spouse;  
}
```

and two instances of P:
a. Tom who's spouse is Annie
b. Annie who's spouse is Tom

Now I am trying to investigate Tom's instance by reflection for serialization purposes.
When I notice value types I write their name and value in an Xml format.
The problem is when I reach investigating reference types such as Tom's spouse, because then a recursion call is made on Annie, but when investigating Annie I will soon get to investigate her spouse Tom again which is not normal, because this will never end.

**Questions**

1. Any ideas how to implement such recursion that will eventually stop?
2. Consider I need to implement serialization function by myself.
   Do you think I can serialize an instance without using reflection in order to investigate it?
   Is there a way to serialize an instance without reflection?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic algorithm... (pseudocode)

```
function examine(m,examined_so_far=[])
{
    result_stuff = something_special
    i = get_unique_identifier(m)
    if i in examined_so_far
        return result_stuff?
    examined_so_far.append(i)

    attributes = get_attributes(m)

    for att in attributes:
        result_stuff.add(examine(att, examined_so_far))
    do_processing(result_stuff)
    return result_stuff
}
```

In english:

Maintain a list of stuff you have already looked at. this can be done either by initializing each M instance with a unique identifier, or by using the memory locations of the instances.

say joe and sue are mutual spouses and you call `examine(joe)`

level 1: result_stuff is initialised (i dont know what you want here),joe's identifier is added to the list

level 2: sue is examined and her identifier is added to the list

level 3: joe is examined and his identifier is already in the list so some result stuff is returned

level 2: gets result from level 3, does some processing and returns relevant result

level 1: gets result from level 2 etc

In terms of your second question...

I'm very rusty with C# so I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this but here is my first thought: Why not maintain an array of names of attributes that should be serialized per class? I'm sure you can access attributes by name somehow. Like in Python the following two statements are eqivalent: `a = some_object.foo` and `a=some_object.__getattribute__('foo')`

What you would do then is have M's serailize-array include an entry with the information `'spouse'` then when serializing this you would iterate over the array. Something like this (also pseudocode...):

```
serial_rep = '{'
for att in self.serialize_array:
    serial_representation += att + ':'
    serial_representation = serialize(obj.__getattribute__(att))
    serial_representation += ','
remove_last_comma(serial_representation)
serial_rep += '}'
```

then when calling `serialise` on an attribute you would need to just check if it has a serialise_array or if it's a basic type.

eg:

```
if type(obj) == int:
    return obj
if type(obj) == str:
    return '"'obj+'"'
if obj.has_attribute(serialise_array):
    serial_rep = '{'
        for att in self.serialize_array:
            etc
```

Comment: If I got you right ,you mean that, I should store the objects id/hashcodes in a map structure which I'll be able to look at while doing recursion.  
Anyway regarding question 2, do you have any ideas?  
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need of reflection here. What you have isn't cyclic dependency (it's really hard to have them in c#). What you have is a loopy class structure.

Several ways to solve this for serialization, the best one is probably to mark the Spouse property [XmlIgnore] and add another SpouseID (or name or whatever works to identify the spouse data)

Comment: Why do you think reflection isn't needed?  
How would you investigate current instance fields and and store them in XML format?

Comment: I wouldn't investigate at all, I'd restructure. Using reflection to write your own serializer is certainly possible but will cause your workload to expand significantly.  I would either inherit or wrap 3rd party classes or modify my own so that standard serializer can be used. This will let you use tested serializer with support for attributes and probably better performing than whatever you come up with at a tiny fraction of the time you'd spend

Answer (score 0):

You could assert some dominance..

```
Class M : P
{
W m_spouse
}
Class W : P
{
M m_spouseof
}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't solve the problem as I can't change classes definition, I need someway to solve the situation as is.